# Google Chrome marks site as unsafe but it's safe

Tags: google-chrome, website, security-warning

I am trying to navigate to mazdev.blogspot.ae/2015/06/sharepoint-thoughts-on-diagnosing.html but I am getting a red screen of a warning stating that

> The site ahead contains harmful programs
>
> Attackers on mazdev.blogspot.ae might attempt to trick you into
>   installing programs that harm your browsing experience (for example,
>   by changing your homepage or showing extra ads on sites you visit).

This happens only for that particular post, the other posts, and even the home page that contains that post are ok.

I scanned using https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/mazdev.blogspot.com and found no issues except `Website Firewall  Not Found   Medium Risk`. What's going on?

Comment: For me it loads without any warning, Chrome 43.0.2357.81 m, Win10

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it's malicious links in adverts, this would explain the intermittent nature as the advert isn't always called. Google's spider may have picked up on these and be flagging them.

Try a plugin like no-script, Adblock plus (or one of its relatives) and see if the issue still occurs.

If this fixes it you may want to contact the owner to let them know.

Comment: Also may wanna clear your chrome cache in the event a previous visit an its cookie are triggering a situation like nate mentioned